# Keep short footnotetext on same page as footnotemark

Tags: footnotes

Is there some way to force `\footnotetext` to appear on the same page as `\footenotemark` as much as possible?

Sometimes when I place a `\footnotemark`, finish writing a paragraph, and then put a `\footnotetext` below the paragraph, the footnote is placed on the next page even when the note is short and can clearly fit on the same page as the mark. I'm not worried about footnotes *spanning* multiple pages, only that as much as possible they are placed on the same page as the mark. Here's (a somewhat long) example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}   % For line spacing

\begin{document}

\doublespacing
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, plac- erat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habi- tant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, plac- erat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habi- tant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.

%% NOTE THE FOOTNOTEMARK BELOW %%
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam.{\footnotemark} Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tris- tique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{
    A short footnote that should be on the same page
}
\end{document}
```

The mark is on the first page, but the note appears on the second page.

Comment: Why do you use \footnotemark/\footnotetext instead of \footnote?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I must have read it somewhere on this site as fixing some other problem that I can't reall. It looks like using `\footnote` might help the issue, but I'd rather a solution using `\footnotemark` if possible. I have more than 100 footnotes and I'd rather not go through them all and replace them if not necessary.

Comment: Sometimes you need \footnotemark/\footnotetext, e.g. when tables are involved, but there is always the danger that the text gets separated from the mark. If all your uses are as in your example there is no way to prevent it. The footnote text is too far away from the mark. So correct your code.

Comment: In an old document of mine, I prevented long footnotes from spreading on two successive footers by using `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000`. But this is just, like, 25 % of what you need, I guess.

Comment: The `para` option of the `footmisc` package “causes footnotes to be typeset as a single paragraph at the bottom of the page on which they occur.”, but the “single paragraph” part might be annoying for you. Edit: actually, if your footnotes are short notes, this might be nice!

Comment: Thanks Alice. Yes, the splitting across pages doesn't bother me. I've looked into para as well, if it could make each footnote on a new line it would work great.

Answer (score 1):

The `para` option from the `footmisc` package might help you if you have lots of small notes.

From the documentation:

> This option (derived from code by Dominik Wujastyk and Chris Rowley) causes footnotes to be typeset as a single paragraph at the bottom of the page on which they occur. In the case that there is only one footnote on the page, no effect will be observed. However, if there are several footnotes on the page, they will be run together in the page foot, each introduced by its footnote mark.